# Partition for dual boot UEFI for Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: uefi, gpt

What should be the scheme partition table for two OS. Windows 8 and Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

When i installed Windows 8 i have three partition:
1 - MSR
2 - Recovery
3 - EFI boot

I need to create that one efi when install Ubuntu such as two OS. As result i had two efi boot partition?

PS: How say russian: Sorri for mu inglish.

Comment: Only one efi partition per hard drive. Each system creates folders for its boot files & UEFI reads the folders to offer boot choices.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read the following two pages:

- [The Ubuntu UEFI wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- My [Linux on UEFI: A Quick Installation Guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

If you still have questions after reading these pages, either post another question or edit this one and make a comment to this answer so that I'll notice you've edited your question.